# Subscript from Selenium Python text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know java fairly well, and I started writing a chess bot using python and selenium, I wrote a method that takes in a list of `move` elements from the website chess.com, and it gives me the moves made by the bot and by me. Right now I have it printing out the text from the latest move made in the chess game, but I just want one of them. How can I subscript the given text to only give me either the former or later 'move'?

Here is the code I wrote:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def get_white_node(self, move):
    white_list = self._driver.find_elements_by_class_name('move')
    sleep(1)
    print("moves:", white_list[move] .text)
```

Here is the output when inputting moves and then printing the latest moves:

```
Input A Move:
e4
moves: 1.
e4
e5
```

If more code is necessary, just ask

Here is the HTML I am scraping:

```
<vertical-move-list class="layout-move-list vertical-move-list" board-id="board-vs-personalities">
<div class="move" data-whole-move-number="1">1.<div data-ply="1" class="white node">e4</div>
<div data-ply="2" class="black node selected">e5</div></div>
</vertical-move-list>
```

Comment: I subscript the given text to only give me either the former or later 'move'? , what you mean by this

Comment: so when I inputted a move into the website 'e4', what I want to do is to store the move I put in(former) and the move that is returned (later e5)

Comment: add the html dom plese

Comment: means the html of the page

Comment: sure let me add it, how would you like me to attach it

Comment: in the questin as code

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by re-writing the method, by splitting the element when converted to text, and then subscribing it t to only get the response I wanted

```
def get_move(self,turn)
    get_list = self._driver.find_elements_by_class_name('move')

    for i in range(len(get_list)):
        move_list = get_list[i].text.split("\\")

    bot_move = move_list[0][6:]
    
    return bot_move
```

this was the output after I fixed the method:

```
Input A Move:
e4

e5
Input A Move:
Nf3

Nc6
```